# Getting Repeated Current Location inside a Service in android?

Tags: android, service, geolocation

I am calling a service were i will get current location at some interval and match the location with a location passed to the service.and if it is in a close range it will buzz the phone.Now i tried to get the current location by `FusedLocationApi`.But i got error when i write this portion

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)//here i got the error
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

I got error in the compiler like:

```
`addConnectionCallbacks` in builder can't be applied to java.lang.Runnable
```

I tried to give `getApplicationContext()` instead of these but same result.I am calling service class from fragment.My whole code:

```
public class LocBuzzService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    public Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        isRunning = true;

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
                    //Double lat = b.getDouble("lat");
                    //Double lng = b.getDouble("lng");


                    //vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    //vibrator.vibrate(3000);

                    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));

                }

               // stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
        isRunning = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Onconnected");
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000); // Update location every second
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                //mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "LocationChanged");
        Double lat1 = location.getLatitude();
        Double lng1 = location.getLongitude();
        Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(lat1)+ ",  " + String.valueOf(lng1));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

What's the problem actually and am i going the right path or is there any easy way to get the current location at some interval??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API) 
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
```

is put in the run() method of an anonymous Runnable class, that means the `this` keyword is referring to that anonymous Runnable class instead of your Service class. Therefore simply changing the code to this will resolve the issue:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API) 
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(LocBuzzService.this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(LocBuzzService.this)
                            .build();
```

Additionally, this code doesn't take very much time to execute, so you can just move it out of the anonymous Runnable and it'll work as well.